# OOP JavaScript - can't assign onclick event handler on page load

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to do a custom tabs system using JavaScript. However, in order to reuse the code I want to write it in OOP style. This what I have so far:

```
function Tabs()
{

    this.tabArray = new Array(arguments.length);
    this.tabArrayC = new Array(arguments.length);
    
    for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++)
    {
        this.tabArray[i] = arguments[i];
        this.tabArrayC[i] = arguments[i]+'_content';
    }
    
    this.setClickable = setClickable;

    function setClickable()
    {   

        for(i=0;i<this.tabArray.length;i++)
        {
                        
                document.getElementById(this.tabArray[i]).onclick = function()
                {
                    
                    alert(this.tabArray[i]);
                                    
                }
            
        }
                
    }
    
}

function init()
{
    tab = new Tabs('tab1','tab2','tab3','tab4');
    tab.setClickable();
}

window.onload = init();
```

Now here's the deal. I want to assign the `onclick` event handler to every tab that has been passed in Tabs 'class' constructor. So later in the code when I write something like:

```
<div id="tab1">Tab1</div>
<div id="tab2">Tab2</div>
<div id="tab3">Tab3</div>
<div id="tab4">Tab4</div>
```

The code which has been set up earlier:

```
document.getElementById(this.tabArray[i]).onclick = function()
{
                    
                    alert(this.tabArray[i]);
                                    
}
```

... would be executed. I hope I explained that well enough. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three issues with your `setClickable` function (**edit**: and an issue with how you're calling `init`):

1. `this` will have a different meaning within the event handler you're generating than you expect. (More here: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html))
2. A closure (a function that *closes over* data like your `i` variable) has an *enduring* reference to the variable, not a copy of its value. So all of the handlers will see `i` as of when they run, not as of when they're created. (More here: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html))
3. You're not declaring `i`, and so you're falling prey to [the Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Here's one way you can address those:

```
function setClickable()
{   
    var i;           // <== Declare `i`
    var self = this; // <== Create a local variable for the `this` value

    for(i=0;i<this.tabArray.length;i++)
    {
                                                         // v=== Use a function to construct the handler
        document.getElementById(this.tabArray[i]).onclick = createHandler(i);
    }

    function createHandler(index)
    {
        // This uses `self` from the outer function, which is the
        // value `this` had, and `index` from the call to this
        // function. The handler we're returning will always use
        // the `index` that was passed into `createHandler` on the
        // call that created the handler, so it's not going to change.
        return function() {
            alert(self.tabArray[index]);
        };
    }
}
```

...and [as `goreSplatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657022/oop-javascript-cant-assign-onlick-event-handler-on-page-load/4657080#4657080) and Felix point out, this line:

```
window.onload = init();
```

...*calls* the `init` function and uses its return value to assign to `onload`. You mean:

```
window.onload = init;
```

...which just assigns `init` to the `onload` event.

---

**Off-topic**: You might consider using the newer "DOM2" mechanisms for attaching event handlers instead of the old "DOM0" way of using the `onXYZ` properties and attributes. The new way is called [`addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener), although sadly Internet Explorer has only recently added that (but it has [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx) which is very similar). If you use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries), they'll smooth out those differences for you (and provide lots of other helpful stuff).

Comment: Oh there are more problems than I thought ;D. Anyway, you might want to include the `window.onload = init();` issue.

Comment: Alright thanks for that. Works like charm - haven't been using js for long time :P

Comment: @Pavel: No worries, glad that helped. @Felix: Thanks for that, I hadn't scrolled down that far. :-)

Comment: I would actually pass "this" as an additional parameter to createHandler(self, index), which means that it doesn't need to be a nested function.

Comment: @Neil: Yeah, that's a good alternate. Having `createHandler` be a nested function is useful if you want to keep it private and if there will be few calls to `setClickable`. If there will be a lot of calls to it, it would be better to do what you said, to avoid creating unnecessary copies of `createHandler`.

Comment: Agreed, you have to choose between privacy and memory.

Answer (score 4):

Problematic:

```
function init()
{
    tab = new Tabs('tab1','tab2','tab3','tab4');
    tab.setClickable();
}

window.onload = init();
```

In this case, `window.onload` will be `undefined`, since `init()` returns nothing. Surely you meant

```
window.onload = init;
```

?